# Is there an alternate way to add COMMENTS to a FILE if it's not available through PROPERTIES?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, comments

Moved here from Stack Overflow. I'm hardly a power user myself, though!

I download a lot of ebooks, mostly .mobi or .pdf format, and I want to keep them straight without having to open the files. On Windows 7 I used the comments field to write notes, and I would show the COMMENTS field in the folder view. It worked great.

To enter comments, I would right-click the file to access its Properties, and IIRC go to Details then type or paste text into the box.

However, when I changed to Windows 10, several file types no longer include the COMMENTS field, including .mobi and .pdf.

Is there an alternate way to add COMMENTS to these files, in Win10, if the field is not readily available in Properties? I don't want to use a separate program or anything complicated, but some kind of extension would probably be what I'm looking for.

Comment: there's no built-in support for PDF files in Windows 7, let alone \*.mobi. Just try a clean Windows 7 installation and look at the blank icon on PDF files. That means the comment field you saw comes from your PDF viewer's add-in